# Worst Case of Quicksort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

what is the worst-case of quicksort? In my opinion, the worst case is when the min/max element is chosen in every step, e.g for the array 3,2,1,4 choosing 1,2,3,4 (each one was min of the reminder of the array when chosen) or 4,3,2,1 (each one was max)  or 4,1,3,2 (4 was max, 1 was min, 3 was max, and  2 was both). In small arrays almost every coise is worst case (for 4 elements, for instance, there are more than those I've listed above), but for large arrays the differene between best/average case and worst case is "huge". By the way, I know this post is duplicate, but I didn't understand from the other posts whether the latter example I've given is correct too or only the former two examples were correct for some reason. Am I right? Is it correct? thanx:)

Comment: You are aware that you could get good answers by just typing that title straight into the Google box, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can get :

Worst case performance  O(n2)

Best case performance   O(n log n) (simple partition)
or O(n) (three-way partition and equal keys)

Average case performance : O(n log n)

[image: big O complexity]